# polymorphism with vector and function?

Tags: c++

I have basically the following code:

```
class A{/*something*/};

class B : public A{/*something else*/};

void foo(B* aux){/*something something*/}

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<A>>content;
    content.emplace_back(new B());
    foo(content[0].get());//error, invalid conversion from A to B
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile this gives the "invalid conversion" error. Is there any way to use the foo function while keeping a vector of A?

Edit: sorry, I should have been  more specific: yes, A is a virtual class. What I'm trying to do is: there are 3 classes that inherit from A (B,C and D), and it would be extremely convenient if I could store them all in a single place (there may be a lot of them, and using one vector for each is a hassle) and as they are all "A", I figured a vector of A would be the best idea, however there are some functions that need specific classes of objects in this vector- like the foo in this case. I *could* just make multiple vectors but I decided to check for suggestions first, thus my question.

Comment: `content[0].get()` is an `A*` you could use `dynamic_cast<B*>(content[0].get())` to get a B* (and check for nullptr since it will be null if its not a B*) but in many cases this is seen to be a bad design.

Comment: You look to be walking into a booby trap and the compiler's trying to stop it from happening. What if there are `A`s, `C`s and `D`s in that `vector`? If you know there are only `B`s and there will only ever be `B`s, why not have a `vector` of `B`s?

Comment: Maybe your polymorphism should be in class A. E.g. a virtual foo() method on A (or pure virtual on an abstract baseclass for A) and then a derived implementation on B.

Comment: Unrelated: avoid mixing `new` and smart pointers. Use the appropriate (`make_shared<B>` in this case) make_ helper function instead. It closes off a few potential failure cases.

Comment: Are you trying to do polymorphism here?  Because this code is how not to do polymorphism.  Change `foo` to `void foo(A* aux){/*something something*/}`  (Which depending on the something, something else, and something something may or may not be polymorphism.)

Comment: Your post mentions "polymorphism", but there is no usage of virtual functions anywhere (assuming you're talking about dynamic polymorphism).

Comment: sorry, I should have been  more specific: yes, A is a virtual class. What I'm trying to do is: there are 3 classes that inherit from A (B,C and D), and it would be extremely convenient if I could store them all in a single place (there may be a lot of them, and using one vector for each is a hassle) and as they are all "A", I figured a vector of A would be the best idea, however there are some functions that need specific classes of objects in this vector- like the foo in this case. I *could* just make multiple vectors but I decided to check for suggestions first, thus my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B is always an A, but A is not necessarily always a B, so your foo function cannot accept an A as a B. You could use a dynamic_cast to check whether A is a B for a specific runtime instance, and then call foo after you know for sure that it is a B, but in most cases that is not the best design (see static vs dynamic polymorphism).

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use polymorphism, perhaps this:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo();
};

class B {
public:
    void foo() override;
};
```

If you typecast from an A* to a B* like you've done, how do you know it's really a B*?

Comment: Better edit the code so it is actually valid for the "normal" usage:

class A{
virtual ~A();
...
virtual void foo() = 0;
...
class B : A {

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the functions that "use" the objects must be outside the classes

Comment: Why? Class assignment?